# When reading audio file with ExtAudioFile read, is it possible to read audio floats not consecutively?

Tags: objective-c, c, cocoa, core-audio

I`m trying to draw waveform out of mp3 file.

I've succeeded to extract floats using ExtAudioFileReadTest app provided in the Core Audio SDK documentation(link: http://stephan.bernsee.com/ExtAudioFileReadTest.zip), but it reads floats consecutively.

The problem is, that my audio file is very long (about 1 hour), so if I read floats consecutively, it takes so much time.

Is it possible to skip the audio file, then read small partial of audio, then skip and read?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, use ExtAudioFileSeek() to seek to the desired sample frame.  It has some bugs depending on what format you're using (or did on 10.6) but MP3 should be OK.