# representing sound graphically as wave

Tags: ios, audio

I Have created an app that records and plays sound and I am looking for a way of showing a simple wave 
representation of the recorded sound, no animation is necessary, just a simple graph.

It would also be nice it is was possible to select a subset of the wave and ofcourrse even more nice
playing that section aswell.

To sum up, what I'm looking for:

1. A way of graphically represent a recorded sound as a wave (e.g as seen in audacity)
2. A way of graphically selecting a subset of the wave representation.

And to clarify a bit further of what I'm looking for:

1. If there is a lib for this I'd be insanely happy :)
2. A hint on what components to best use for handling the graph drawing.
3. A tip on how to handle the selection within the graphical component.

Comment: What should the axes of the graph be? Volume vs. time? Time-integrated volume vs. frequency?

Comment: Beta: Yes, Time for x-axis, and whatever gives the best representation(volume?) for the y-axis.

Comment: You already know how to write an app, and I presume you know how to manipulate the sound file, so it's a question of displaying graphics and/or a GUI. I don't know how much you know about those subjects, so I suggest you edit your question to clarify what it is you need help with. (I know very little about iOS graphics, so I probably can't help you.)

Comment: I am mainly looking for help with the graphical stuff, I.e what components to use for this and why. Added a little bit more info to clarify my request, thanks for the feedback, Beta.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I already did this in another application and have been struggling with it for a while ...

You would divide the number of samples the audio file has by the number of pixels you have to display the graph. This gives you a chunksize.
For all the "buckets" you calculate the min and max value and display them in relation to the sample resolution used.

Can provide further examples if needed.

---

Regarding the graphics stuff:
(I am not an iOS developer but Mac programming isn't that much different I think.)
Just create a subclass of NSView ( should be UIView in iOS ) and override the drawRect method.
Then just create a function which you pass an array of values for your file and draw a bunch of lines to the screen. It's no black magic here!!

This is really nothing you would need a library for!
And, as another positive aspect : if you keep it generic enough you can always reuse it.

Comment: Thanks, you override-strategy sound like a great way of doing this. I guess that the same class also could catch and store an x-interval representing the selection made by pinching and use those coordinates for drawing and overlay in the drawRect-method aswell. Sorry for the long comment, but I kinda got a bit carried away :)

Comment: I always like to help out!! Especially if it's in my "home territory". I also have a diploma in audio-engineering ;) So hit me up if you need more info. Best

Comment: Started out Implementing the graphing as you proposed and it is excellent. I've only been doing simple playing-taskt with tha AVAudioPlayer before so any help on how to read info about an mp3 that is usable for the graphing would be really appreciated!

Comment: You have to decode it first to get the actual values. This question seems to be addressing this exact issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6902730/when-reading-audio-file-with-extaudiofile-read-is-it-possible-to-read-audio-flo  I was using the mpg123 library because I was using C++ instead of objc