# How to get the audio graph for sound file in wave form?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, ios6, ios4

I want to implement a functionality in which I want to get the audio graph in the form of image for the audio file I am passing.
I searched everywhere but didn't get the useful stuff.

Can anybody tell me the technique or way to get this or some source code or library to get this work done.

The output that I want for the audio file is can de described from the image.

[image]

Here are few links that I found in my research ....

1) http://timbolstad.com/2010/03/14/core-audio-getting-started/

2) http://timbolstad.com/2010/03/16/core-audio-getting-started-pt2/

3) [representing sound graphically as wave](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9296937/representing-sound-graphically-as-wave)

Comment: Why is this being upvoted? This question does not show any research attempts and asked for (among others) libraries, which are off topic. Cool that you have a picture, but what language is this even in. What have you tried?

Comment: Didn't see it for myself but sounds promising. https://github.com/gyetvan-andras/cocoa-waveform

Comment: @ParvezBelim, did you find a solution?